# TypeScript: Why is that my filter method cannot narrow the type and eliminate the undefined and false from the array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this type from the `d.ts` file of an API

```
type EventConfigurations = {
  Event1: {
    Enabled?: boolean;
  };

  Event2: {
    Enabled?: boolean;
  };

  Event3: {
    Enabled?: boolean;
  };
};
```

Now that I have this data coming back from the response of that API call

```
const eventConfigurations: EventConfigurations = {
  Event1: { Enabled: true },

  Event2: { Enabled: false },

  Event3: { Enabled: true }
};
```

and now I want to map the data to

```
enum EventDesc {
  Event1 = "XXX",
  Event2 = "YYY",
  Event3 = "ZZZ"
}

type MyEvent = {
  eventDesc: EventDesc;
  topic: EventTopic;
};

const eventConfigurations: EventConfigurations = {
  Event1: { Enabled: true },
  Event2: { Enabled: false },
  Event3: { Enabled: true }
};

const events: MyEvent[] = (Object.keys(eventConfigurations) as Array<
  keyof EventConfigurations
>)

  .map(
    (eventType) =>
      eventConfigurations[eventType].Enabled &&
      ({
        eventDesc: EventDesc[eventType],
        topic: EventTopic[eventType]
      } as MyEvent)
  )

  .filter(Boolean);
```

And the compiler raised an error saying that, the `events` could be either

```
(false | MyEvent | undefined)[]
```

But I added `.filter(Boolean);` at the end of the `map`, it should eliminate the possibilities of it being either `false` or `undefined`.

Here is the live demo https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-yonath-ttdhn?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Your code doesn't throw any errors on the codesandbox... and when I `console.log(events)` i get the objects...

Comment: @MosiaThabo add `MyEvent[]` as the type for `events` you will see a ts error

Comment: Oh I see, sorry man. I couldn't reply on time, was a bit busy. The problem was your `map` was returning undefined when the condition is false. That's why you had those warnings... Check my answer below on how you can remedy your approach using map and filter.

Comment: I think you really should `filter` on `eventConfigurations[eventType].Enabled` first and then do the `map`, so you don't need to abuse `&&`

Answer (score 12):

TypeScript's standard library does [have a signature for `Array.prototype.filter()`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/2dd7a4bf939ffac4002ea9c76651166ba457ac70/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1355) which will narrow the type of the array, but it will only use that signature if the compiler recognizes the passed-in callback as a [type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) whose return type is a *type predicate* of the form `paramName is SomeType`.  And, unfortunately, the compiler is not currently able to *infer* that a callback (like `Boolean` or `x => !!x`) is a type guard; you have to *annotate* it as such.

(See [microsoft/TypeScript#16069](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16069) for the feature request to use some sort of control flow analysis to interpret certain functions as type guards.)

Here's one such annotated callback:

```
const truthyFilter = <T>(x: T | false | undefined | null | "" | 0): x is T => !!x;
```

or if you really want you can use `Boolean` as the implementation with a type assertion like

```
const truthyFilter2 = Boolean as any as <T>(x: T | false | undefined | null | "" | 0) => x is T;
```

That is sort of a generic truthiness detector, although TypeScript doesn't really have a good way to represent all possible falsy values in the type system (`NaN` is unrepresentable for exaple).  Anyway you can see it in action like this:

```
function fn(arr: Array<false | undefined | MyEvent>) {

  const item = arr[0];
  if (truthyFilter(item)) {
    item.eventDesc; // okay, no error
  }
```

And now if you use it with `filter()` the compiler will narrow it as expected:

```
  const myEvents = arr.filter(truthyFilter)
  // const myEvents: MyEvent[]
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CiA3C5kDeAsAFDLIS7gAiEAzggFzJ1hSgDmA3KeWAPYAHYExZtOPEgF9epBPxCtkbAK5gAFugBiwADaQoyALzIAPABUAfAAoAHs3PIAPsni66KFyBW7dz5CogACYQMKAQQf4ARFH+AAwAlMy2yMB0yI5GlsgAhDm2knIKSqoa2noGAEzGyABC-Py6EHAgyHDpLeht6RY29hn+bh7+3r7+gSFhIBHRsS6JxtkpaRmFJKQwgQhgwAquINZwUFDMAILHcOimQ54BwaHhkS4YOHhglgmEpLzI8opgqUgAFsakcoABtOIAXUk5GAMGQ1lKmh0+mg1mAwISn2IZHIgIgQIAdJQ3rQGFxkAB6KnIfgAa0uABpkCB+BRjvwoD8ZOs8X8lCkTGCiWE0VBrPVGs0QAk1uQBQCgVgqGB0sLjqKKujkeVxXKfjTfsUlSq3nRmC9VeCod8+VIgA)

Comment: We use this approach a lot across the codebase. Worth mentioning, that a type guard should be used exactly like this, as is. Wrapping it into another function would not work (I've seen it leading to confusion a few times). `arr.filter(item => truthyFilter(item))` - this won't work, because the wrapping function itself is not a type guard.

Comment: Right, wrapping into another function without annotating it as a type guard fails for the same reason that `item => !!item` fails: the compiler just can't infer it.  I think there's an issue specifically asking to enable type-guard-wrapping like this, hold on.... [microsoft/TypeScript#10734](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10734).

Comment: Thanks! I was like "no way nobody has thought about that!" :)

Comment: You forgot to include `null` in your list.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```js
const filterUnwanted = (value: any): value is MyEvent => ('eventDesc' in value && 'topic' in value)
```

Or instead of `Array#map` followed by `Array#filter`, consider `Array#reduce`:

```js
const events = (Object.keys(eventConfigurations) as Array<keyof EventConfigurations>)
  .reduce((acc, eventType) => (
    eventConfigurations[eventType].Enabled ? acc.concat([{
      eventDesc: EventDesc[eventType],
      topic: EventTopic[eventType],
    }]) : acc), [] as MyEvent[],
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think your `reducer` solution is better than my `map` + `filter` solution. However can you explain why the filter doesn't eliminate the false and undefined? I don't understand why we have to use `type guard` here

Comment: As far as I know, it's just a technical limitation of TypeScript's inference engine.

Comment: The problem wasn't with the inference issue. `map()` must return something for every item on the array that is being mapped. And the condition used within `map` in this case returns undefined when `Enabled === false`, and since undefined is not of type `MyEvent` Typescript will cry out lout. What you want to rather do is returned an empty object of `MyEvent` and then filter and drop that empty event object.

Comment: The problem is with the inference. Passing anything falsey through `.filter(Boolean)` will return `false` and therefore filter it out. The TypeScript inference engine is unable to narrow the type here. There has been an [open issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16655) for years.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading this, chances are that you have tried doing something like this in TS:

```
const a: Array<number|undefined> = [1, 2, undefined]
const b = a.filter(Boolean)
b.map((item) => item*item) -> error, item is possibly be undefined
```

At this point you ask yourself, what am I doing wrong.

Hint 1 - The error message on line 3 says item is possibly undefined.

Hint 2 - You need to modify line 2 to somehow tell typescript that b is an array of numbers.

Hint 3 - You can use is keyword in TS. A brief explainer on how the is keyword works

This code tells js that if this an item passed isNumber check, this means it is definitely a number.

```
function isNumber (item: number | undefined): item is number
  return typeof item === 'number'
```

Solution

```
const a: Array<number|undefined> = [1, 2, undefined]
const b = a.filter((element): element is number => typeof element === 'number')
b.map((item) => item*item)
```

Now coming to the main question: Why is TS not intelligent enough to type filter automatically? Well honestly I don't have a good answer to that so will leave that unanswered until I have more clarity.

Comment: I refuse to implement something so horrendously complicated for such a simple idea. If there's not better solution, then maybe it's time to just accept the drawbacks of typescript and start using `as` or `any`

Answer (score -1):

There's two approaches to this:

**Option 1**:

Return an empty `{} as MyEvent` when condition in `.map()` is false, because currently `undefined` is returned. And then perform `filter` after.

```
const events : MyEvent[] = (Object.keys(eventConfigurations) as Array<
  keyof EventConfigurations
>).map((eventType) =>
      (eventConfigurations[eventType].Enabled ?
      ({
        eventDesc: EventDesc[eventType],
        topic: EventTopic[eventType]
      } as MyEvent) : {} as MyEvent) // Return an empty object if Enabled == false
  ).filter(performFilter); // filter by checking if objects returned are empty or not

const performFilter = (obj : MyEvent) => Object.keys(obj).length > 0;
```

---

**Option 2**:

Filter the list before you use map to create new objects.

```
const events: MyEvent[] = (Object.keys(eventConfigurations) as Array<
  keyof EventConfigurations
>)
.filter((event)=>eventConfigurations[event].Enabled)
.map(
  (eventType) => ({
      eventDesc: EventDesc[eventType],
      topic: EventTopic[eventType]
    } as MyEvent)
);
```