# .filter(Boolean) typeguard not working in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typeguards

```js
const coercedVersions: string[] = versions
   .map((version) => semver.coerce(version)?.version)
   .filter(Boolean);
```

This throws an error
`Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.`
when `strictNullChecks` is on.

I don't understand why the `.filter(Boolean)` is not able to typeguard the array.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541843/typescript-why-is-that-my-filter-method-cannot-narrow-the-type-and-eliminate-th

This question already has the answer to my query.

Comment: Yeah it does. Thanks