# typescript array not assignable after map and find

Tags: typescript

The following code

```
const s: string[] = ["x", "y", "z"].map(i => ["x"].find(t => t === i));
```

This causes an error "*Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.*" as `find` gives `string | undefined`. So I was hoping adding a filter can fix that, like:

```
const s: string[] = ["x", "y", "z"].map(i => ["x"].find(t => t === i)).filter(i => i);
```

But this didn't work, why?

TS version 4.2.3

Comment: TypeScript won't infer a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), `.filter((i): i  is string =>` will help.

Comment: Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/63541843/3001761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know for sure that the `find` call here will **never** return `undefined`, you can use an assertion with '!':

```
const s: string[] = ["x", "y", "z"].map(i => ["x"].find(t => t === i)!);
//                                                                   ^
```

Otherwise you will have to write a guard:

```
function isDefinitelyAString(val: unknown): val is string {
    return typeof val === "string";
}

const s: string[] = ["x", "y", "z"].map(i => ["x"].find(t => t === i)).filter(isDefinitelyAString);
```

---

You can also inline the guard like @jonrsharpe suggests:

```
const s: string[] = ["x", "y", "z"].map(i => ["x"].find(t => t === i)).filter((i): i is string => typeof i === "string");
```

Comment: Note that `.filter((i): i is string => i)` on its own isn't OK, because only booleans are compatible with type predicates.

Comment: I just want to add that `!` operator is always dangerous, so if there is any solution to avoid it, you should do it. Guard will be better for 100%

Comment: That is why I said if you know for sure, then you can use it, but still it is risky.

Comment: Thanks, this is quick! Why can't I just add ! to the end of `filter`?

Comment: '!' asserts that the preceding expression cannot be undefined or null. After the filter the type is (string | undefined)[] and so it will not work.

Comment: I replaced `typeof i === "string"` with `!!i`